# Unexpected Behavior on printing a Char Set on C

Tags: c, file-io, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am getting [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFqlO.png) unexpected chars when I try to print the string inside of a file. How can I deal with this situation?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *readFile(char *filename)
    {
        char * buffer;
        long length;
        FILE * f = fopen (filename, "r");
        if (f)
        {
            fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
            length = ftell (f);
            fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
            buffer = malloc (length);
            if (buffer)
            {
                fread (buffer, 1, length, f);
            }
            fclose (f);
        }
        return buffer;
    }

int main() {

    char *firstS = readFile("file.txt");
    printf("%s \n", firstS);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not `NUL` terminating your string.  Instead, do

```
buffer = malloc(length+1);
```

and then after you read in the file

```
buffer[length] = '\0';
```

When `printf` reads past the allocated memory for `buffer`, it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), `printf` happily reads along until it finds a `'\0'`.  Also note you should initialize `buffer` to NULL:

```
char * buffer = NULL;
```

and check for that back in `main` before you print.  If there's a problem opening the file for instance, you return an uninitialized `buffer` to `main`, and trying to read from that is another UB invoker:

```
char *firstS = readFile("file.txt");
if (firstS != NULL)
{
    printf("%s \n", firstS);
}
else
{
    // print error message to your liking
}
```